# How to apply postman filters in django?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, postman

I am trying to implement a POST method from a JSON object in Django but I do not know how to apply this POST method. I have the following code:

**Method POST from Postman**

```
{
  "filter": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "field": "CreatedOn",
        "operator": "gte",
        "value": "2017-02-12 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "field": "CreatedOn",
        "operator": "lte",
        "value": "2017-03-12 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "field": "VIP",
        "operator": "eq",
        "value": "YES"
      }
    ],
    "logic": "and"
  }
}
```

**Code Snippet to parse a JSON to Python**

```
def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/ansdb/api/rows/dev/ect/tickets",timeout=15) as url:
    response_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    user_id = [value['user_id'] for value in response_data]
    print(user_id)
    return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False)
```

**JSON object that I want to filter**

```
[{
id: 1003384,
user_id : 0001
CreatedOn: "2017-02-16 15:54:48",
Problem: "AVAILABILILTY",
VIP: "YES",
Vendor_CODE: "XYZ12345",
Week_id: "07",
},
{
id: 1003338,
user_id: 0002
CreatedOn: "2017-02-15 13:49:16",
Problem: "AVAILABILILTY",
VIP: "NO",
Vendor_CODE: "XYZ67890",
Week_id: "09",
}]
```

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: The POST method filters the JSON by a range of dates and when I apply this method in Postman I receive the JSON filtered by those dates. I need to filter this JSON  so I can handle the data faster than with the complete JSON.

Comment: `filter this JSON` I meant be more specific about this. What do you want to filter? What are you trying to achieve by filtering etcetera.

Comment: I want to filter the dictionaries that are contained between a given range of dates. If run the code snippet I will obtain all the dictionaries that are contained in the JSON from January 2016 to June of the present year. I only want the dictionaries of 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested and off the top of my head. Replace the date range as you see fit as well as inclusive or exclusive condition.

```
from datetime import datetime

START_DATE = datetime.strptime("06/01/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")
END_DATE = datetime.strptime("06/07/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")

response_data = filter(lambda x: START_DATE < datetime.strptime(x['CreatedOn'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") < END_DATE, json.loads(url.read().decode()))
```

Comment: Although you did not test the code I implemented this snippet and I was able to filter the data without recurring to the requests library which is another method to filter the data with a POST method. Thanks a lot!